# JavaScript - getElementById (what does it do?)

Tags: javascript

I wan't to know what does `getElementById` do in js?

we also use that in CrossSiteScripting attacks.

Answer (score 7):

Most html constructs have an element called "id" which must be unique in the whole html page. Such as `<div id="uniqueDiv1">`. `getElementById` returns that HTML object. In my example, `getElementById("uniqueDiv1")` returns that div. You can then use it to set a style or do something with it.

Comment: And in Internet Explorer 6/7 it'll return an element whose "name" attribute has that value too. In other words, Internet Explorer is broken in this case. (I think 8 fixes this, but I'm not 100% sure.)

Answer (score 1):

It returns an element from the HTML document that has the ID attribute set to the value you ask for. For example, the JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('myId');
```

will return the first element found that matches that ID, such as

```
<a id="myId">Link</a>
```

I say the "first element found" because that's exactly what will happen--by definition, IDs must be unique in the page. Each HTML page must have only 1 ID of the same name. If you violate this rule, you'll get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

it gets a DOM Element By its Id

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` allows you to access elements of a page.

Lets use this page as an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDIV">Hello World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`document.getElemenById('myDIV').innerHTML` will give you `Hello World!`
`document.getElementById('myDIV').style.display = "none"` will hide the div tag.

If you want to look at what all it can do on a live page I would suggest getting Firefox and install the Firebug addon. This will let you see all of the DOM things and play with them without having to re-save a page.